# How to create query with twice a connection to a table in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I need get two city names with one query:

For example:

City table:

```
+---------+----------+
|  Pana   |   Name   |
+---------+----------+
|   THR   |  Tehran  |
|   LON   |  London  |
+---------+----------+
```

In Model: **from_city** is *THR* and **to_city** is *LON*

```
public function scopePrintQuery($query, $id)
{
    $join = $query
        -> join('cities', 'cities.pana', 'flights.from_city')
        -> join('cities', 'cities.pana', 'flights.to_city')
        -> where('flights.id', $id)
        ->get([
            'flights.*',
            'cities.name as from_city'
            ??? for to_city?
        ]);
    return $join;
}
```

Now, I need get **from_city** name and **to_city** name in this query.

The query does not work with two joins from one table!

How to create this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With straight SQL you could give each joined table an alias - e.g.

```
SELECT flights.*
FROM flights as f
 JOIN cities as fromCity on fromCity.pana = f.from_city
 JOIN cities as toCity on toCity.pana = f.to_city
WHERE f.id = 3 --
```

With Eloquent, use [select()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) to specify select fields. Also use [DB::raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions) to use raw SQL (e.g. giving an alias to table like `DB::raw('cities as toCity')`.

```
public function scopePrintQuery($query, $id)
{
  $join = $query
    -> join(DB::raw('cities as fromCity'), 'fromCity.pana', 'flights.from_city')
    -> join(DB::raw('cities as toCity'), 'toCity.pana', 'flights.to_city')
    -> where('flights.id', $id)
    ->select([
        'flights.*',
        DB::raw('fromCity.name as from_city')
        DB::raw('toCity.name as to_city')
    ]);
    return $join->get();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use the eloquent model with defining the relationship.

Also for more detail visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

crate two model -- 
1st is "Flights"

```
<?php


class Flights extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'flights';

    /**
     * Get the From City detail.
     */
    public function fromCity()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\City', 'Pana', 'from_city');
    }

    /**
     * Get the To city state.
     */
   public function toCity()
   {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\City', 'Pana', 'to_city');
   }

}
```

2nd Model is "City"

```
<?php
class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'city';
}
```

Now for fetching

```
Flights::where(id, $id)->with('toCity', 'fromCity')->get();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me, Why you use `from_city` to `to_city` function?

Comment: When you are querying, then its specify which relationships should be used for eager loading. for more detail please visit on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading