# Laravel: How to query data from multiple table?

Tags: php, database, laravel

The db have 3 tables chars, tags, and chars_tags

chars has the following columns:

```
id | char_name
```

tags has the following columns:

```
id | tag_name
```

chars_tags has the following columns:

```
id | char_id | tag_id
```

I always use the code below to get the data, because last time the char table has another column called 'tag_id', now they remove the 'tag_id' column and change it to pivot table which is 'chars_tags'

```
$char = chars::where('id', '=', 1)
     ->with('tags:id,tag_name')
     ->get();
```

So how can I get the char with tag now?

Comment: Have you add relationship in model ?

Comment: May be this will be help you Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515792/3016038

Comment: @DsRaj return $this->hasMany(tags::class, 'id', 'tag'); I only have this in my chars model

Comment: I think this is a Many to Many relationship (but you need to confirm about that: not enough behaviour in your quesiton) so you should follow: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many  and switch to belongsToMany() both in Char and Tag models...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up your models using a many to many relationship between chars and tags

```
class Char extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'chars_tags', 'char_id');
    }
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function chars()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Char::class, 'chars_tags', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can eager load your related tags with chars

```
$char = Char::with('tags')
            ->where('id', '=', 1) 
            ->get();
```

or you could use `find()` if you need a single object

```
$char = Char::with('tags')->find(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sql joins: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)

```
DB::table('chars')
->where('chars.id', 1)
->leftJoin('chars_tags', 'chars_tags.char_id', '=', 'chars.id')
->leftJoin('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'chars_tags.tag_id')
->get();
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but im looking for the relationship method