# Laravel where and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables 
Item :

- id
- title

mark_item:

- id
- item_id

I would like to make a join between these two tables

```
  $item_mark = Item::select('item.*','mark_item.*')
                        ->join('mark_item', 'mark_item.item_id', '=', 'item.id')
                        ->where('item.title','=','ITEM_TEST')
                        ->get();
```

**But when displaying I have redundancy for the title of the item, knowing that I have a single title called ITEM_TEST in the database**

```
Example : 


    ITEM_TEST
     -Mark1
    ITEM_TEST 
     -Mark2
    ITEM_TEST 
     -Mark3
```

I would like to display :

```
ITEM_TEST

         -Mark1

         -Mark2

         -Mark3
```

Comment: what do u want ???

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: try by replacing hasOne to hasMany relation between Model https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515792/3016038

Comment: presumably you are relating `item_test` to 3 marks which is why you get it 3 times. Use [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) to get something that makes more sense.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi i edited the post

Comment: @Jerodev I edited the post

Comment: `join` is default `innerjoin`, are you looking for `leftjoin`? question is not clear to me. you may have single `ITEM_TEST` in `Item` table but three marks in `marks_item` table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of relation you have between both the tables -

If its a one-to-one relationship go with the below given query. 
If you want columns just add them to the select separated by a comma.

```
$items = DB::table('item')
            ->select('item.title')
            ->leftJoin('mark_item', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->get();
```

[Check Larvel Query doc for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Answer (score 0):

**Your tables**

```
item(id, title)
mark_item(id, item_id, name) //here assuming name filed contains 'Mark1', 'Mark2' etc
```

From these table it is clear that you have `OneToMany` relation between `item` and `mark_item`. In laravel you can easily define these relationship and fetch data through that.

First you need to create model for both these tables

Item Model

```
class Item extends Model {
     $table = 'item'; 
     public function marks(){
        return $this->hasMany(ItemMark::class);
     }
}
```

ItemMark Model

```
class ItemMark extends Model {
     $table = 'item_mark'; 
     public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
     }
}
```

Now fetch data

```
$item = Item::with('marks')->where('item.title','=','ITEM_TEST')->first();
echo $item->title;
foreach($item->marks as $mark){
   echo $mark->name;
}
```