# Displaying column value in response - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller, i have this raw query. I am trying to build a shoe shop online store. The code below is grouping similar items entered by my clients

**Controller**

```
   $items_counted = DB::select( DB::raw(" select * from (
          SELECT  COUNT(names) as products
          FROM Shop
          GROUP BY names
          )));
```

If clients, select Masorini shoes and John Foster shoes, the response should be `[{Masorini : 2 }], [{John Foster : 2 }] and not [{Product : 2 }], [{Product : 2 }]`.

I am trying to get the value(name) of what is being counted in the database

How can i achieve this?

PS: New laravel user

Comment: make a relation hasOne in model and used in with to get the values. this is laravel core for ex-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515792/3016038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion is to use the query builder (or even better the eloquent ORM).

Here's what you can do:

```
$items_counted = DB::table('Shop')
                   ->groupBy('names')
                   ->select('names', DB::raw('COUNT(names) as products'))
                   ->pluck('products', 'names');
```

When you send this as a JSON response it should have the format you need.

Comment: this is how my response looks like {"\"0-3\"":2,"\"Overpriced\"":1,"\"Reliable\"":1,"\"Very satisfied\"":2}

Comment: How can i take away the ` //` to look like `{"0-3":2,"Overpriced":1,"Reliable":1,"Very satisfied":2}`

Comment: Are the quotes stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, the quotes are stored in the database

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't store them in the database but you can possibly remove them if you change the select to `->select(DB::raw('JSON_UNQUOTE(names) as names'), DB::raw('COUNT(names) as products'))`. this needs MySQL 5.7+ and will also prevent the use of any index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$items_counted = DB::select(DB::raw("select names, sum(names) as sum from Shop GROUP BY names");
$result = [];
foreach ($items_counted as $item) {
    $result[$item->name] = $item->sum;
}
```